# Add user generated content to a database in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

In page_load, I create a table and fill it with data gathered from a database.  Then after allowing the user to modify it, I need to make the changes to the database.  But I'm not sure how to do this.  I have been looking around and now am more confused then when I started. My code to create the table looks like this:
         delList.Controls.Clear();

```
            Table tbl = new Table();
            tbl.ID = "tbl1";
            tbl.BorderWidth = 1;
            delList.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

This code gets added to a placeholder:

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="delList" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I want to have a button at the bottom of the page to allow the user to select in order to save the changes but I can't figure out how to do this.  Mostly because there will be a lot of rows that need to be updated.  I was thinking it might be easiest to parse through the table using javascript and then somehow calling a function to make update the database one row at a time. But I'm not sure if this is even possible.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the user currently editing this record? There are many built in data binding options for data editing in asp.net using the grid, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you used a control that is specific to this kind of operation. I mean a control like [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

> GridView displays the values of a data
>   source in a table where each column
>   represents a field and each row
>   represents a record. The GridView
>   control enables you to select, sort,
>   and edit these items.
>
> The GridView control is used to
>   display the values of a data source in
>   a table. Each column represents a
>   field, while each row represents a
>   record. The GridView control supports
>   the following features:
>
> 1. Binding to data source controls, such as SqlDataSource.
> 2. Built-in sort capabilities.
> 3. Built-in update and delete capabilities.
> 4. Built-in paging capabilities.
> 5. Built-in row selection capabilities.
> 6. Programmatic access to the GridView object model to dynamically set properties, handle events, and so on.
> 7. Multiple key fields.
> 8. Multiple data fields for the hyperlink columns.
> 9. Customizable appearance through themes and styles.

Answer (score 0):

i dont get how the User Can modify content in a Table, unless you have some form Controls like Textbox, Dropdown list?

You should be creating form fields dynamically, and adding it to a container/form on the Page along with a button (which could do a postback/ or handle JavaScript).

You Could iterate through all controls in a parent container or add custom attributes to your form elements, do that you can identify those fields in JS/Clientside.